# Dynamic alignment of a toggle button

Tags: android

I have been working with android over past few months, but am still not sure of how to align a button dynamically. I did it using xml but then it becomes strongly typed ... which in my case is not required. So anyone please help me n tell me how to place a toggle button with the help of java code and not with xml.
For example:
If i want to place a toggle button to the extreme bottom right of the screen. Please help am stuck on this.

Here is my xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="348dp">
          <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
           android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="27dp" 
           android:layout_marginTop="55dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and java part is here.....

```
package org.in;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class AsbdActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);

        EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    }
}
```

even after setting gravity the editext remains at the place specified in xml.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the layout of an item during run time then you need to use the `LayoutParams` class.  Each `Layout` types has a child `LayoutParams` class.  Here is a simple example that shows how to do it.

Let say I have a `TextView` contained in a `LinearLayout` and I want to change the `TextViews` width and height.

```
int newHeight; 
int newWidth;
LayoutParams lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, newHeight);
textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

It can be a lot more complex than this, but there are lots of tutorials on the web that explain how to do this in more detail.

One thing to remember, that when changing the `LayoutParams` on a view you must use whatever `ViewGroup` that contains it to generate the `LayoutParams` object or it won't be respected by the `ViewGroup`

Comment: Thank you 4 ur reply slayton , but what i want is positioning the textview to xtreme below right corner, lets say screen size is 800x480  and am using a relative layout which covers the whole screen, so in this case how will i use LayoutParams to place textview , i tried a lot but all in vain....

Comment: @Amul, instead of changing the width and height like I do in my example you are going to want to change the `layout_gravity` value in the `LayoutParams` object.

Comment: I have reposted question in proper format now just help me out with editext placement at bottom of screen

Comment: Did you not read my answer? You can't change the gravity on a `View`. You need to create a `LayoutParams` object, set the `gravity` on that, and then call `view.setLayoutParams(latoytParamsObject)`

Comment: Also consider remove the `layout_alignParentTop` and `layout_alightParentLeft` as those are probably forcing your `EditText` to stay in the top left corner of their parent.